# Vlan translation and Swapping

Tags: vlan, vpls, metro-ethernet

Heey, all

As an ISP provider, We are trying to connect Multiple customer sites via our Mpls core.

our plan to give each customer site a different vlan ( c-vlan) and then translated to S-vlan to transport the frames through our network. we know about vlan map as we map each customer vlan to s-vlan but this is Symmetrica operation which I read on cisco article

(On an interface configured for VLAN mapping, the specified C-VLAN packets are mapped to the specified S-VLAN when they enter the port. Symmetrical mapping back to the customer C-VLAN occurs when packets exit the port.)

But this won't work in our design because we want to assign a different vlan at each customer site.

I read on junpier articles they have a technology vlan swapping which swap c-vlan with new s-vlan by discarding the c-vlan tag and adding a new s-vlan tag.

This is written in juniper article:
(VLAN translation (swapping) replaces an incoming C-VLAN tag with an S-VLAN tag instead of adding an additional tag. The C-VLAN tag is therefore lost,)

Is there any similar technology in cisco?

Thanks